# How to send a custom status and error message if no data found using Node.JS/express and axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, error-handling

If no user is found (it's just an example to understand error handling), I want to send a custom message such as

```
res.status(404).send('no user');
```

my client never receives that and instead I get:

> [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404]

What am I doing wrong? I cannot find any other solution and have been researching for a while now. Also wonder how I could send a custom status (if no data found it's 404 but what if I want to send 200)?
**node express**

```
router.get('/getuser', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({_id: req.user._id});
        if (!user) {
            res.status(404).send('no user');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }

    } catch(error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});
```

**frontend**

```
const trycatch = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(example.com/trycatch)
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses with a status code of 400 or more are treated as errors by axios. As a consumer, you can only react to that in the `catch (error)` clause, for example:

```js
catch (error) {
  switch (error.response.status) {
    case 404: return "no user"; break;
    default: return error.response.data;
  }
}
```

But you can influence which statuses cause errors with the [`validateStatus`](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) option of the axios request.

**Summary:** Either you distribute your code between the `try` and the `catch` block, where the `try` block code handles successes (status < 400) and the `catch` block handles errors (status ≥ 400). Or you use `validateStatus` to change what counts as a success and what counts as an error.

Comment: but my question is how can i send custom error messages. if i keep my backend code, logging (error.response.data) will not show my custom msg, only axios error '[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404]'

Comment: thank you. I actually thought it wouldnt log anything but it does. Previously I was logging error and didnt see the custom message, when I logg error.response.data (as you said), I can see the error message. Im just very confused as error (catch(error)) is an object. Why can I only see the msg if I log error.response.data, not just error? Also as I understand now I can only see the custom error message, if I send status of 4+, not 200. So is there any way for me to send a message in case theres no user but have the status be 200 as: res.status(200).send('no user')?

Comment: Use [` validateStatus`](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) to have all statuses treated as successes (see last sentence in my answer).

Comment: ok thank you and thats the only way to do it? Im just wondering because I would not want to make a status of 200 become a status thats throws an err as it seems not right so I just want to be able to get a response (200) when there is no data but a if (!user)res.send(...) wont arrive in my client

Comment: or what is it bad practise in such cases where I dont have data to just send a 200 ?

Comment: Sorry, the code in my answer is meant to run on the client, therefore it cannot contain `res.send`. My fault. I have edited my answer again.